# Does Nullspace(A) = Nullspace(C) imply Nullspace(AB) = Nullspace(CB)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I recently thought of the following linear algebra statement:

*For arbitrary matrices $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{C}$, we have
$ \mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{N}(C) \implies \mathcal{N}(AB) = \mathcal{N}(CB) $*

Is this statement correct?

I came up with the following proof attempt:

*Assume $\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{N}(C)$. Then,
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
x\in\mathcal{N}(AB) & \iff x\in\left(\mathcal{N}(B) + \left(\mathcal{N}(A)\cap\mathcal{C}(B)\right)\right) \\
 & \iff x\in\left(\mathcal{N}(B) + \left(\mathcal{N}(C)\cap\mathcal{C}(B)\right)\right) \\
 & \iff x\in\mathcal{N}(CB).
\end{split}
\end{equation}*

Is this proof correct?

(*I denote nullspaces and column spaces with $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{C}$, respectively.*)

Comment: Your title assumes the equivalence of the nullspaces of $A$ and $B$, but you assume this of $B$ and $C$ in your proof. Which is it?

Comment: Good catch, edited the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not true that $\mathcal{N}(AB) = \mathcal{N}(B) + \bigl(\mathcal{N}(A) \cap \mathcal{C}(B)\bigr)$. For one, if the matrices aren’t square, then these vector subspace operations might not be able to be performed due to differing underlying spaces.

A more appropriate equivalence is $x \in \mathcal{N}(AB) \iff Bx \in \mathcal{N}(A)$. From which it follows that

$$\begin{align}
x \in \mathcal{N}(AB) &\iff Bx \in \mathcal{N}(A) \\
&\iff Bx \in \mathcal{N}(C) \\
&\iff x \in \mathcal{N}(CB),
\end{align}
$$

whenever $\mathcal{N}(A) = \mathcal{N}(C)$.